# Errors when deploying Data Hub 7.5.2

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-10

When deploying a fresh install of DH 7.5.2 into a clean ML 10.0-9 Server, I get the following error:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':mlDeployApp'.

> class com.marklogic.hub.deploy.commands.LoadUserModulesCommand tried to access private method 'void java.net.URLDecoder.()' (com.marklogic.hub.deploy.commands.LoadUserModulesCommand is in unnamed module of loader org.gradle.internal.classloader.VisitableURLClassLoader @161727d0; java.net.URLDecoder is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2m 1s

---

Additional Info:

### Gradle 7.5.1

Build time:   2022-08-05 21:17:56 UTC
Revision:     d1daa0cbf1a0103000b71484e1dbfe096e095918

Kotlin:       1.6.21
Groovy:       3.0.10
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.11 compiled on July 10 2021
JVM:          18.0.1 (Oracle Corporation 18.0.1+10-24)
OS:           Mac OS X 12.5.1 x86_64

---

Any help installing and deploying would be appreciated.

Frank

Comment: First suggestion would be that you gather more insights by following the suggested next steps : stacktrace, debug, scan options

Comment: I was able to try older versions of Gradle and Java.... and the combination of Gradle 6.9 and Java 11 seems to work to get the deploy to work.

Answer (score 2):

Need to use Java 11 - the underlying MarkLogic Java Client works on Java 8 and Java 11, but not yet Java 17 or 18. Support for that is coming soon.